# How do I make the following table appear at the top of the current page with table*?

Tags: tables, floats

I can't seem to use the float top function.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Experimental Results}
\begin{table*}[t!]
\begin{tabularx}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Your example is still not working and if I make it working by adding a width and a column declaration it doesn't show the problem. Nevertheless: `table*` makes sense only with option `twocolumn` for `article` class. You should use `table` (without `*`). For `table*` (with `twocolumn`) it is a documented feature to put tables not on the current page but at the next one.

Comment: @Schweinebacke It's not a bug, it's a feature.  `:)`

Answer (score 0):

If you insert some text into the tabular the code works and the table is placed in the top.
Of course you should consider the comment of Schweinebacke.
The `table*` environment is used to make a tabular over both columns of a `twocolumn` `article`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Experimental Results}
\begin{table}[t!]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
        \hline
        a & b\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]